# C# (.NET), веб-запрос методом GET, используя куки и аутентификацию

Tags: c#, .net, http, get, httpwebrequest

Моя цель - считать http страницу с [этой ссылки.](https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_checkout)

Использую HttpWebRequest и HttpWebResponse, но страница требует куки и аутентификацию. Fiddler дал мне общую информацию о запросе через браузер [(скрин)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue4YL.png).
В коде постарался добавить все заголовки и основные куки с фиддлера, но возможно где-то допустил глупую ошибку, или попросту что-то пропустил:

```
string userData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
string uri002 = "https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_checkout";
HttpWebRequest request002 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri002);
request002.Host = "opskins.com";
request002.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
request002.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + userData);
request002.Method = "GET";
request002.Referer = "https://opskins.com/?loc=shop_search&app=730_2&sort=lh";
request002.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
request002.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
request002.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
request002.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
request002.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

request002.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request002.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://opskins.com"), new Cookie("opskins_csrf_token", textBox4.Text));
request002.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://opskins.com"), new Cookie("opskins_login_token", textBox5.Text));
request002.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://opskins.com"), new Cookie("PHPSESSID", textBox6.Text));

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request002.GetResponse();
StreamReader responseRead = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
MessageBox.Show(responseRead.ReadToEnd());
responseRead.Close();
```

При запуске вылетает следующая ошибка:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>   The request was aborted: The connection was unexpectedly closed.

Запрос был прерван: Соединение было неожиданно закрыто.

Что нужно исправить в коде? Добавить оставшиеся куки или искать другой способ для считывания http страницы? К слову на сайте стоит защита от ботов, но я не думаю что это влияет на мой запрос. Скрин с фиддлера для моего запроса оставлю в комментариях. Удачного дня.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lw4xZ

Comment: а внутри ошибки описания нет?

Comment: попробуйте `request002.KeepAlive = false;`

Answer (score -1):

Смотря на вопрос начинаю подозревать что вам проще будет использовать Selenium WebDriver напару с PhantomJS браузером.
Скорее всего это даст вам именно то что нужно и с меньшими усилиями.

С оговоркой на то, что куки нужно будет вручную сериализовать и рассериализовать т.к. вебдрайвер не умеет этого делать.

Comment: Что сериализовать?

Comment: Если не будет сериализироватся класс с куками самого веб-драйвера, то написать свой, который будет поддерживать сериализацию и сериализировать его.